# Node-sass is not recognized by command line

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-tool, node-sass

I'm trying to set up node-sass, following the [instructions on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/why-npm-scripts/). Node and npm are installed correctly, and the node-sass installation worked too. When I go to run `node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css src/scss`, though, I get an error message stating

> 'node-sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I've done a fair bit of Googling and searched [Stack Overflow directly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode-sass%5D+not+recognized). My question isn't about "node" not being recognised as a command. I know node is working as I can run `node -v` and `npm -v`, and node-sass was successfully installed after running `npm install --save-dev node-sass` (there's a folder in node_modules) and no errors appeared in the command line.

Other information: I am running Windows 10 and just did a clean install of node and npm before trying to use node-sass.

EDIT: I uninstalled and reinstalled with -g thanks to @Bhavik's suggestion, and it's now working

Comment: You need to do `npm install -g node-sass` to install it globally.

Comment: so I can't run it from the command line without installing it globally?

Comment: It should be available in your `PATH` variable to be used. Other way can be in `package.json` you can have `scripts` where you can create `"scripts": { "node-sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css src/scss"` and then run it using `npm run node-sass`

Comment: Thanks, it's working now

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to install it globally

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

Or add it in `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "4.5.0"
},
"scripts" : {
    "node-sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css src/scss"
}
```

And then do
1. `npm i`, which in this case would be similar to `npm install --save-dev node-sass`
2. `npm run node-sass`

Reference: [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), [npm-run-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

Comment: When I run `node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css src/scss` directly from the command line, it works, but not if I run it as a script. Is that a result of installing globally? If I want to use node-sass in scripts, does it need to be a local install?

Comment: Not sure why it happens, npm-run-script works with packages installed in both globally & locally. ***In addition to the shell's pre-existing PATH, npm run adds node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts.*** from [npm-run-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

Comment: Yarn: `yarn global add node-sass`

Answer (score 5):

You can simply run this code

1. npm install -g sass
2. sass --watch sass:css

Hopefully work

Answer (score 1):

npm commands check "node_package" folder and try to run things there. You can try

```
npx run scss
```

to install scss and then run it, even if it is not installed before.

Answer (score 0):

The below solves the problem

```
yarn global add node-sass-chokidar
```

Comment: why `node-sass-chokidar` if there exists `node-sass`?

Comment: @Gabi Wissotzky with then upper command i got an error error /home/humayun/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem don't worry too much. Just go to **package.json** file and add this code

```
"devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "4.9.2"
},
"scripts" : {
    "node-sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css/ scss --recursive"
}
```

and just save the file.

And run this command,

```
npm run node-sass
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

**node-sass v4.13+**

1. Install node-sass in your project locally

```
cd <root path of your project>
yarn add -D node-sass
// or
npm install -D node-sass
```

2. Add a script to your package.json

```
"scripts" : {
...
  "compile:sass": "node-sass --recursive --watch <sass directory> --output <css directory>",
...
}
```

3. Run the script from the command line

```
yarn compile:sass
// or
npm run compile:sass
```

Answer (score 0):

First, run `npm install -g node-sass` as others have pointed out.

Now, the target of the command (`sass.cmd`) is not located in the current working directory. For it to still be able to run, its location must be in your PATH (or Path) environment variable.

For me, the path is: `C:\Users\Guy\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Make sure to restart any terminal/IDE you were trying to run it in before trying again. Otherwise it won't recognize the new environment variable.