# 'node-sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: installation, node-sass

'node-sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! natours@1.0.0 node-sass: `node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css src/scss`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the natours@1.0.0 node-sass script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\horlah\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-10-10T01_19_47_695Z-debug.log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node-sass is not recognized by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518621/node-sass-is-not-recognized-by-command-line)

Comment: node and npm is okay but node-sass is not installed yet. I got this error                                        npm ERR! path C:\Users\horlah\Documents\ADV_CSS_SASS\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\semver\bin\semver